# Oracle join on two xmltables

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g, xmltable

In an attempt to make every two item into one from the following XML,

```
<items>
  <item><a>a1</a><b>b1</b></item>
  <item><b>b2</b><a>a2</a></item>
  <item><a>a3</a><b>b3</b></item>
  <item><a>a4</a><b>b4</b></item>
  <item><a>a5</a><b>b5</b></item>
  <item><a>a6</a><b>b6</b></item>
</items>
```

I came with this solution:

```
select * from xmltable ( '/items/item[position() mod 2 = 0]' passing
    xmltype('
<items>
  <item><a>a1</a><b>b1</b></item>
  <item><a>a2</a><b>b2</b></item>
  <item><a>a3</a><b>b3</b></item>
  <item><a>a4</a><b>b4</b></item>
  <item><a>a5</a><b>b5</b></item>
  <item><a>a6</a><b>b6</b></item>
</items>') columns
  "id" for ordinality,
  "a" varchar2(10) path 'a',
  "b" varchar2(10) path 'b'
) x,
xmltable ( '/items/item[position() mod 2 = 1]' passing
    xmltype('
<items>
  <item><a>a1</a><b>b1</b></item>
  <item><b>b2</b><a>a2</a></item>
  <item><a>a3</a><b>b3</b></item>
  <item><a>a4</a><b>b4</b></item>
  <item><a>a5</a><b>b5</b></item>
  <item><a>a6</a><b>b6</b></item>
</items>') columns
  "id" for ordinality,
  "c" varchar2(10) path 'a',
  "d" varchar2(10) path 'b'
) y 
where x.id = y.id;
```

The problem is that it does not recognize the second table in the ON clause:

```
ORA-00904: "Y"."ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 29 Column: 18
```

It rendered me helpless. I have tried multiple subqueries, subqueries within subqueries but there were no hope.

Thanks for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made your XMLTable columns with [quoted identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm). You either need to quote the references too:

```
where x."id" = y."id";
```

Or change the column clauses to not be quoted, which is simpler:

```
id for ordinality
```

... etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will mark it as answer as soon as 8 mins pass.